# how can I create alarm when server in AWS goes down?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

how can I receive a notification in Google chat or email when running jar process goes down in AWS server ? I have created status check alarm in EC2 instance but not working when i stop the running program.

Comment: The title is misleading, seems you want to create an alarm when the application is unavalable, not the server (ec2 instance)

Comment: yes correct, i was assuming that when application is unabailable accordingly network packets in/out will go down so i can put treshold to give an alarm. Currently i can see alarm but can not receive an email notification

Comment: Email is a different topic, you can assign an sns notification on the alarm and set a  email recepient on the sns topic. I don't consider the network as a reliable metric, it is not directly bound to the application

Comment: is it possible to send directly to google chat?

Comment: That's a completely different topic, it is better to open  new question.

Answer (score 2):

The cloudwatch monitors logs and metrics from the AWS resources, not really taking care of the application out of box. There are multiple ways to do so, depending if the application can provide some http enpoints or post its metrics

Just out of blue there are multiple options

- If using an application load balancer, the load balancer has a metric for healthy instances in the autoscaling group
- Using [CloudWatch Cannary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Create.html)
- The application could post its own [custom metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

Comment: To explain further... If you wish to be notified when the application is _not_ running, then there needs to be (1) a way to indicate when the application _is_ running and (2) a way to notice when that indication changes. Thus, your application could send an Amazon CloudWatch Metrics 'custom metric' when it _is_ working, and then you could configure an Amazon CloudWatch Alarm to notify you when the metric is _not_ being received (eg a count of the metric over the past 15 minutes is less than 1).